# How to change the default port of tomcat runing on cPanel and remove the app name on the address

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, cpanel, whm

Lets say my website address is www.example.com, I have uploaded my java application on the server but it is just accessible on www.example.com:8080/MyApp how to change it to the normal url ? which is www.example.com

Comment: Whats the negative vote for!!!??

Answer (score 0):

Edit server.xml file located in the conf directory. Look for the connector which should be set to 8080. It should be like the following...

> Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
>
> connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />

Change the 8080 to 80 as below and restart your Tomcat service.

> Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
>
> connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />